# Livewire Saving checkbox values as they are checked or unchecked

Tags: php, laravel-livewire

I have been trying to save checkbox values as they are checked by the user. No save button for this part is needed.

This is a many-to-many relationship and therefore, it’s the relation table that gets updated with the new values.

The array returned by Livewire to updatedSelected() is the same as initial values from the database and that is where I am stuck.

The problem is when values exist in the DB, load the page, uncheck one or more and the array returned to updatedSelected() is the same as it was initially loaded on page load.

On checking a checkbox the values are updated properly as I get the full array of values as expected.

When unchecking, what I am expecting is only the values that are left checked to properly sync the model.

**If you have any clues on this, your help would be appreciated!**

**pefumes.php**

```
public $selected = [];

protected $rules = [
     "selected.*" => "required"
];

public function updatedSelected( $values )
{
    $this->validate();

     if( $this->plant->id != null )
     {
         $this->plant->perfumes()->sync(
             array_map( "intval", $values )
         );
     }
}
```

**perfumes.blade.php**

```
<div class="auto-grid-placement auto-grid-item">
    @foreach( $perfumes as $perfume )
        @php
            $slug = slugafy( $perfume->name );
        @endphp
        <x-form.label for="{{ $slug }}-{{ $perfume->id }}" class="{{ $disabled }} checkbox-item px-2 py-2 inline-block">
            <input wire:model="selected" type="checkbox" id="{{ $slug }}-{{ $perfume->id }}" class="" value="{{ $perfume->id }}" {{ $disabled }}> {{ $perfume->name }} - {{ $perfume->id }}
        </x-form.label>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

To further express the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get through this by changing the `wire:model="selected"` to `wire:click=”savePerfumes( $perfume->id)”` by calling a method to filter and save the input values. This is the example that got me on the right track: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNuWLHiRn-o

I must then conclude that the approach of calling the wire:model=”selectedPerfume”, the set array, on every checkbox is probably better, if not made for, single-use checkboxes and these are not checked from values from the DB on load, like most examples you see.

If one needs to check and uncheck checkboxes, this is my approach:

**The view**

```php
<div class="auto-grid-placement auto-grid-item">

    @foreach( $perfumes as $perfume )
        @php
            $slug = slugafy( $perfume->name );
            $checked = ( in_array( $perfume->id, $selectedPerfumes->toArray() )? "checked='checked'" : "")
        @endphp

        <x-form.label for="{{ $slug }}-{{ $perfume->id }}" class="{{ $disabled }} checkbox-item px-2 py-2 inline-block">
            <input wire:click="savePerfumes( {{ $perfume->id }} )" type="checkbox" id="{{ $slug }}-{{ $perfume->id }}" name="selectedPerfumes[]" {{ $checked }} class="" value="{{ $perfume->id }}" {{ $disabled }}> {{ $perfume->name }} - {{ $perfume->id }}
        </x-form.label>
    @endforeach
    @error( "selectedPerfumes" )
        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        <!-- /.error -->
    @enderror
</div>
```

**The function to save**

```php
// Rules
 protected $rules = [
        "selectedPerfumes"  => "array",
        "selectedPerfumes.*"    => "required|integer"
    ];


 public function savePerfumes( $perfume_id )
 {
     $this->validate();

     if( $this->selectedPerfumes->contains( $perfume_id ))
     {
         $this->selectedPerfumes = $this->selectedPerfumes->reject( function( $value ) use ($perfume_id) {
             return $value == $perfume_id;
         });
     }else{
             $this->selectedPerfumes->push( $perfume_id );
     }

     if( $this->plant->id != null )
     {
         $this->plant->perfumes()->sync(
             $this->selectedPerfumes
         );
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public $selected = [];

protected function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        'selected' => 'required|array',
    ];
}

public function edit()
{

    if ($this->validate()) {
        $data = [
            'name' => $this->name,
            ...
        ];

        $plant = Plant::where('id', $this->plant->id)->update($data);

        if (!empty($this->selected)) {
            $selectedId = Perfume::whereIn('id', $this->selected)->pluck('id');
            Plant::findOrFail($this->plant->id)->perfumes()->sync($selectedId);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @abdulmajeed. But what does that achieve? It does not get the actual values of the checkbox when one is checked or unchecked.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" wire:model.defer="selected" wire:key="selected{{$perfume->id}}" value="{{ $perfume->id }}"  />